# How to exclude certain values from elastic nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST query to filter records from elastic.

The following query will filter records based on phrase and list of sourceIds. But I would like to exclude some documents from the result if their URL contains ideaArticles list.

```
var result = ElasticSearchClientConnection.Client.Search<T>(s => s
                .Query(q => q.Match(p => p.Field(f => f.Body).Query(phrase))
                            && q.Terms(p => p.Field(f => f.SourceId).Terms(sourceIds))
                            && !q.Terms(p => p.Field(f => f.URL).Terms(ideaArticles))
                ).Take(take));
```

Comment: [Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with `must_not` clause should help :)

Comment: I've tried that, it does not help me. ElasticSearchClientConnection.Client.Search<T>(s => s
                .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.MustNot(m => m.Terms(p => p.Field(f => f.URL).Terms(ideaArticles)))
                )));

Comment: Could you share index mapping?

Comment: yes. Client.CreateIndex(this.DefaultIndex, c => c
                .Settings(s => s
                    .NumberOfShards(numberOfShards)
                    .NumberOfReplicas(numberOfReplicas)
                    .BlocksReadOnly(false)
                )
                .Mappings(m => m
                    .Map<PercolatedQuery>(mm => mm
                        .AutoMap()
                        .Properties(p => p
                            // map the query field as a percolator type
                            .Percolator(pp => pp .Name(n => n.Query))))));

Comment: @Rob Do you know how can I pass a list of string to MatchPhrase? It will work with one phrase but I have a list of phrases    ElasticSearchClientConnection.Client.Search<T>(s => s.Query(q => !q.MatchPhrase(p => p.Field(f => f.URL).Query("http://feeds.mashable.com/~r/Mashable/~3/Y_1a8VwnsEk/"))));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue with MatchPhrase. But since I had a list of phrases, I had to create a query on the fly.

```
var result =
                ElasticSearchClientConnection.Client.Search<T>(s =>
                    s.Query(q => q.Match(p => p.Field(f => f.Body).Query(phrase))
                                 && q.Terms(p => p.Field(f => f.SourceId).Terms(sourceIds))
                                 && BuildMatchPhraseQueryContainer(q, ideaArticles)).Take(take));
```

and this is the method to create the query on the fly

```
private QueryContainer BuildMatchPhraseQueryContainer(QueryContainerDescriptor<T> qd, List<string> phrases)
        {
            QueryContainer queryContainer = new QueryContainer();
            foreach (var phrase in phrases)
            {
                queryContainer &= !qd.MatchPhrase(m => m.Field(f => f.URL).Query(phrase));
            }
            return queryContainer;
        }
```